# A beginner's error (args[0])

Tags: java, args

I started to read a book on java, and there the author showed this program. But I get errors in the line with args[0]. The author writes that this line has to read string. Is it true?

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(args[0]);

    System.out.println("Amazing");
}
}
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at Main.main(Main.java:5)
```

Comment: "But I get errors" Please post the full error message. My guess is you don't have any args but that's a guess

Comment: see Elliott answer then :)

Comment: Please don't put stack traces or code in the comments. Edit your question and add them to that. Also, show how you are running your program.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute the program, you specify the class that contains the `main` method and then command line arguments. `args[0]` is the first command line argument. You need to provide it when you run the program.

```
java -cp . com.something.Main A B C
```

where A is `args[0]`, B is `args[1]` and C is `args[2]`.

Comment: And, you can use `args.length` to see how many arguments were given.